# Cannot GET / error in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am developing a simple MEAN stack application. I am using angular routing to redirect to a page based on the Id of the item clicked like this:

```
   when('/story/:id', {
      template: '<news-detail></news-detail>'
   })
```

When an item is clicked it should go to a page like this : http://localhost:3002/story/58fbcf765865db1d8da94b41

but on that page I get a "Cannot GET /story/58fbcf765865db1d8da94b41" node error.

from back end I have tried this:

```
 app.get('/story/:id', function(req, res){
   if(req){
    var id = req.params.id;
    PostProfile.News.findById(id, function(err, item){
        if(item){
            console.log("found")
            res.send(item)
        }
    })
  }
})
```

This solution just displays some raw json on the page

```
 {"_id":"58fbc2834f675c1cdb7dc628","title": .....
```

What is the walk around for this and how can I use angular to make the request by id without going through nodejs first.

thanks alot.

Comment: That's a webserver (express I'm assumng) error and not a node error. It's possible you have a node error as well, but either your code is not outputting the error or you have not found where to look (stderr, stdout or logs). To start with, I'd handle the error in your callback: `if (err){ console.error( err ))` in your findById.  Also, the `if(req)` feels very superfluous. If you don't have the req-object in your express routed methods then you really have something strange going on...

Comment: Step 1, check your network tab and inspect the call to try to find out how far it gets (what you have there is a server-response so move on!). Step 2: Check server-side that the call is received, logs, output. Step 3: No error? Make sure your code outputs errors in some way or another. Step 4: When you have the real error check back with SO, but you can probably figure it out the rest by then! :)  You real problem here is to find the real error message.

Comment: And just to straighten out the last few bits. `when('/story/:id', {`  this is an angular route. It assumes `[webroot]/story/:id`.  Your backend is likely not the same as your webroot. Yes, it is of course possible to configure express or nginx or whatever to catch /story/ and make sure the backend gets it, but it's *usually* not the case. The normal thing is to clearly separate front & back. (for example `/api/story/:id` or another port `localhost:4004/story/:id'.)

Answer (score 0):

to go to some page you have to do res.render
Eg:

```
    router.get('/story/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    PostProfile.News.findById(id, function(err, item){
      res.render('somePage', {
        pageTitle: item.title,
        body: item.body
     });
   })
});
```